# SSRS 2008 Dataset move up and down

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, report-designer

Using single transaction when processing the datasets, I would like to change the order my datasets currently appear under the folder Datasets. Is it possible to move up or down any created dataset? I didn't manage to do it so far, and I'm not very enthusiast in creating my 25 DS again...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a backup first!

On the menu: View-Code. This will put you into the XML view of your report.

Search for the `<Datasets>` tag. Select the dataset to move by cutting from the tag `<DataSet NAME="MyDataSet">` to the closing `</DataSet>` tag. Paste where you would like it to be. Your datasets will be re-ordered in the dataset dropdown.

On the menu View-Designer to get back to the report designer.

Comment: I think that is needed to reopen report after saving and closing xml. I need to do that